# SQL query to insert via dapper works one way but not the other (queries included)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Strange error from one query but not the other and I am not sure why one works but not the other.

Btw the second `Insert` statement handles on FieldA = single value @var1,  FieldB = array of values and FieldC = single value @param3.

One more thing is, FieldA + FieldB is composite unique constraint (but not a foreign key)

Working version:

```
Declare @var1 int 

Insert into table1 (field1, field2) 
values (@param1, @param2); 

select @var1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Insert into table2
    Select FieldA = @var1, FieldB = Id, FieldC = @param3 
    from table3 
    where FieldD = @param4;

Select @var1;
```

Error version (Nothing much different but just the alignment of FieldA,B,C):

```
Declare @var1 int 

Insert into table1 (field1, field2) 
values (@param1, @param2); 

select @var1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Insert into table2
    Select FieldA = @var1, FieldC = @param3, FieldB = Id 
    from table3 
    where FieldD = @param4;

Select @var1;
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: BTW, Dapper has nothing to do with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you assumed (wrongly!) that the aliases you're using in the `select` clause of the `insert....select` statement determines what columns the values will go to - Well, that's not how it works.

Just like with `insert...values`, you should specify the columns list (even though it's optional) in the `insert` clause, and just like in the `values` clause, the order of the columns returned by the `select` clause means what columns they will go in to.

In fact, aliases in `insert...select` clause are meaningless except as readability aids - the database will ignore them - but if they help readability, then it might not be a bad option to keep them anyway.

The first version only worked by accident - because either the order of the columns in the `select` clause matched the order of the columns in the table itself - or worst, it didn't match but the data types of the columns that didn't match was compatible to the order of the columns in the select list, meaning you've inserted the wrong data without getting any indication about it.

A correct code would be something like this (omitting the first insert statement):

```
Insert into table2(FieldA, FieldB, FieldC)
Select @var1, Id, @param3 from table3 where FieldD = @param4;
```

and

```
Insert into table2(FieldA, FieldC, FieldB)
Select @var1, @param3, Id from table3 where FieldD = @param4;
```

This way, your `insert...select` statement does not depend on the order of the columns in the table itself, and will not break if you add columns to your table (unless you add non-nullable columns with no default values) or if you change the order of the columns in the table (which I agree is unlikely but I have seen it done, more often then you would expect).